# NMAP to scan ip and ports from file

Tags: nmap

I want to scan IP and port from a file as below:

```
192.168.1.2 443
192.168.2.100 8443
192.168.3.99 80
192.168.4.11 443
```

How can I do that? I know there is option to take IP from a file using `-iL` but how can do with IP and port as for each IP there is a specific port.

Comment: why not scan all 3 ports on every IP from the list?

Comment: Why not run nmap with the specific options you want per target as a separate scan?

Comment: @schroeder thanks. But I have very long list of IP and port. How can I do in a single shot?

Comment: You could write a script to do that (_launching separate nmap scans_) since I think nmap doesn't support it...

Comment: @game0ver any hint to develop that script?

Comment: @ghostrider just do what I suggested: make the IP and ports a variable and pull in from your file

Comment: @schroeder appreciated. Can u write the syntax. Sorry my ignorance, I am new to nmap

Comment: @ghostrider it's not an nmap problem but a scripting problem, and this is not the right place for scripting help

Comment: @ghostrider just read the file, split each line to host and port and launch the nmap command through your script.

Comment: @game0ver better to go through once and gather all unique ports and targets. Write the targets to a temporary file, join the ports together with commas, then scan those ports on those targets. `perl -lanE'$h{$F[0]}=1;$p{$F[1]}=1;END{$,="\n";open$i,">ips";say$i keys%h;exec"nmap -iL ips -oN wat -p".join(",",keys%p)}' input.txt`

Comment: @bonsaiviking yes there are many implementations, that's why I didn't post a script. It also depends on the actual format, e.g. does the OP want to check only one port per ip and if more in what form they appear on the file? , so I guess depends on what the file actually looks like. Also if he only wants to check if the certain port is open there is a much faster way to do that using masscan. BTW nice perl one-liner :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only do it using a shell script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare an array for ip's
declare -a ips=("192.168.1.2" "192.168.2.100" "192.168.3.99" "192.168.4.11")

# declare an array for ports
declare -a ports=("443" "8443" "80" "443")

# now loop nmap through the above array combos
for (( i=0; i<=3; i++ ))
do
   nmap $ips[i] -p $ports[i]
done
```

Or you could do the same in C/C++ using the system command!

Answer (score 4):

As of Nmap 7.70, this is not a feature that the Nmap development team is interested in developing. Full discussion can be found in [Issue #1217](http://issues.nmap.org/1217), but the current best practice is to scan all desired ports against all targets.

EDIT: To everyone doing some big shell script to scan each port and host individually, you'll be here all day waiting for that to finish. Accumulate all the unique ports and targets and scan them in one go. You'll end up scanning a few ports on some systems that you didn't intend, but overall it won't take that long. And like everything else, it fits into one line of Perl:

```
perl -lanE'END{$,="\n";open$i,">ips";say$i keys%h;exec"nmap -iL ips -p".join(",",keys%p)}$h{$F[0]}=$p{$F[1]}=1' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just wrap it in bash and call it good. Using the file format you specified above this would work.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f $1 ] 
then
    echo "Error: Must supply file"
    exit
fi 

while read -r line 
do
    host=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1`
    port=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f2`
    echo "Scanning $host : $port " 
    nmap $host -p $port
done < $1
```